# Rails association, nested forms and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here are my simplified models

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offer
end

class Kitchen < Room
end
```

I'm using STI for Kitchen, cause it seemed the right way to express what I wanted to do (I'm probably wrong).

I want to be able to create an Offer with Rooms in it. I have 'regular' rooms that are instances of Room directly, and more specified rooms such as a Kitchen which can have an extra attribute.

I'm using cocoon to create nested form, it works great to create an offer and add regular rooms. But how can I add kitchens ?

Maybe it's an architecture issue more than an implementation issue. How would you manage to do something like this ?

Comment: Why not just do simply one `Room` model with column `room_type` where you can just mark `kitchen`, `bathroom`, etc.?

Comment: In addition to type, I want to add fields depending on the type. I didn't like the idea of having nil values for thoses attributes if they are present for all Rooms. But maybe it's the way to go. Other solution would be to have one table per type.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add JSONB column `data` to your `rooms` table. Then you can use [jsonb_accessor](https://github.com/devmynd/jsonb_accessor#single-table-inheritance) gem to elegantly manage STI.

I assume you have `type` column already so you can do something like:

`Kitchen.create(offer_id: 1, name: "Great Kitchen", description: "It is great!")`

Notice: `description` would be attribute of JSONB `data` column. In addition you can [create indices](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/) for JSONB attributes and even do queries. From my experience, you want to keep JSONB as place to store additional info and less for heavy queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess it would do the job but it feels a bit hacky. I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @Monstercrunch If you want to do STI without nil values in columns, then this is the way to go IMHO. Actually I find it handy to have additional info in JSONB column since you can add attributes later without migration. Another option is not to do STI, but then you have to create table for each room type.